# ¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de un cliente al seleccionar su nombre en una lista desplegable?

Tags: base-de-datos, pdf, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy creando un formato de facturas dónde hay una lista desplegable **(hoja1, b12)** con los nombres de los clientes frecuentes. Esta lista desplegable obtiene los nombres de la **(hoja2, columna "a")**. En la columna **"a"** están todos los nombres, En la **"b"** la dirección y en la **"c"** el numero de tlf.
Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar, en la lista desplegable, el nombre de un cliente automáticamente se agregue en el formato de la factura la dirección **(hoja1,b13)** y el num de tlf **(hoja1,b14)** de el cliente seleccionado.
He buscado y no consigo como hacerlo. Estoy empezando en esto de apps Script. Yo tenía un formato parecido en Excel vba pero en app Script no hallo como hacerlo.
Y si es posible también cómo exportar el formato de la factura automáticamente en un archivo PDF.

Comment: Añade el código que tengas hasta ahora para que puedas recibir mejores respuestas

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Como te han sugerido en el comentario anterior, muestra lo que has intentado así como una breve descripción de lo que has buscado como se sugiere en [ask], así como también limita tu pregunta a un sólo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza esta fórmula SOLAMENTE en Hoja1!b13

```
=arrayformula({vlookup($B$12,Hoja2!A:B,columns(Hoja2!A:B),false),vlookup($B$12,Hoja2!A:C,columns(Hoja2!A:C),false)})
```

Automáticamente traerá los datos que necesitas.
Saludos!